# How to create a nested dictionary with this given input in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, key, overwrite

I am given this input in separated lines and I want to create a nested graph.

Input:

```
a b 3
b c 4
a c 10
```

Desired nested dictionary:

```
{'a': {
    'b': 3,
    'c': 10 },
 'b': {'c': 4 }
}
```

This is my code, however, it overwrites the same key.

```
for rec in range(2, num_lines):
    first, second, length = lines[rec].split()    
    d[first] = {}
    d[first][second] = length
```

Comment: In which language? Python?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check and see if the first key is already in the dict before you set it to a dict.

```
out = {}
for line in input:
    first, second, third in line.split()
    if not first in out:
        out[first] = {}
    out[first][second] = third
```